# SQL Server 2008 erroneously returning SQL Authentication failed

Tags: authentication, sql-server-2008

I am attempting to connect to SQL via SQL authentication.  On SQL Server I receive Login succeeded, yet via code I get Login failed for user 'geneva'.  I verified the login in SSMS and am able to connect via Windows authetnication.  The sql user has full rights.  Tried via java/.net code, really unsure why I am unable to connect via SQL Auth.

```
Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=GenevaWorkflow;User ID=user;Password=password
```

The environment is SQL Server 2008/Windows 2008.  Very frustrating being all I want is to connect via SQL authentication and SQL Server I set to mixed mode authentication.

Comment: have you checked TCP/IP configuration? (Microsoft SQL Server Configuration Tools). Sometime, usually in express edition, this protocol is disabled and no connection is allowed from external clients.

Comment: Take a look at the second part here for your user. http://kbase.gfi.com/showarticle.asp?id=KBID002804 This caught me for ages too. Also check the SQL Server logs in SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

Enable sql logins in server properties (from management studio) and restart sql server.